# Can I use Google Adsense For Search (AFS) ad units with AMP?

Tags: adsense, amp-html

I need to put on my site Google Adsense for Search(AFS) ad units (see screenshot).

[image: AFS]

But I'm looking in AMP documentation and don't find this ad type here.
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/amp-ad.html

Is there a way to do this or AMP is not supporting these ads?

Regards, Kadmos

Answer (score 1):

There's a Github issue discussing this topic: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2659

If the integration you want is this: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9879?hl=en then you should experiment with putting it inside an amp-iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to put CSA ads on AMP pages

```
<amp-ad width=auto height=300
    type='csa'
    layout='fixed-height'
    data-afs-page-options='{"pubId": "partner-pub-id", "query": "flowers"}'
    data-afs-adblock-options='{"width": "auto", "number": 2}'>
</amp-ad>
```

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/google/csa.md

Answer (score 0):

AMP currently supported providers like AdSense. You can place ads on your page by using the amp-ad component. See the sample snippet.

```
<amp-ad width="320" height="250"
        type="adsense"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-8125901705757971"
        data-ad-slot="7783467241">
</amp-ad>
```

You need to specify which provider you want on the `type` attribute and then set up some other attributes that are specific to that provider.

You can also check this [blog](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/12/whats-the-fuss-with-googles-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp/) for reference.

Comment: My question was more specific and was referring to Google Adsense for Search type (I've put it's screenshot).
What you've written is available in documentation and I've put also documentation link above.But is their Supported ad networks list is missing google AFS type.

My question is about it.